# Possible cause of hang in PyQt application?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, freeze

I have a PyQt application that hangs.

Qt 4.7.4 (64-bit)
Python 2.6.1
GCC 4.2.1
OSX 10.6.8

The location of the hang varies. If I disable/rewrite one location of hang, the hang occurs somewhere else shortly afterward.

The application performs searches that might return thousands of custom data objects, each of which might contain fifty child objects.

Logging reveals the hang tends to occur in a loop that creates these custom objects.

ALSO

The application uses threading, however the hang occurs even when I disable these threads. (I am using [Laszlo Nagy's stack trace tool](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577334-how-to-debug-deadlocked-multi-threaded-programs/) to verify this. The hang occurs even when only the main thread and the stack tracer thread are running.)

The application reads and creates image files. It seems unlikely an I/O lock is the culprit, but I have yet to rule it out.

I WONDER

Is there a limit to the number of python objects I can create?

Is there some other limit I might be reaching?

I'm not doing any explicit object deletion for garbage collection. Should I?

Are there any other usual suspects?

EDIT (8/13):

- QTimer.singleShot is good to know and a hot lead -- however this app doesn't use singleShot.
- When the application hangs, it claims 100% CPU (and about 140 MB of memory.)
- I will try strace ASAP and see what it reveals.

Comment: Try running your program using `strace`, it shows system calls your program makes. This should enable you to see a hang on a blocking syscall when one occurs.

Comment: Are these searches and the data objects they return separable from the interface? If not, they should be. This won't solve the problem, but it will make debugging it much easier.

Comment: What does your memory/cpu usage look like when the app is "hung"?

Comment: I can think of one 'usual suspect': excessive use of QTimer.singleShot in a multithreaded environment (even if the second thread has no interaction with the timer).

Comment: This is not easy to do, but it is an effective debugging technique: Try to pare down the program into the shortest, simplest runnable example that still demonstrates the problem. Either you'll end up with something you can post and we can all look at, and/or you'll discover the nature and source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried dtruss (rough equivalent of strace on OSX) but didn't derive much help from the results.

At last I took a coworker's advice and rolled back my source to its last known non-hanging state. Then I reintroduced changes class by class.

The culprit was **a class inheriting from two different QWidget classes**, e.g.:

```
class undoableWidget(QWidget) :
...

class tearableWidget(QTabWidget) :
...

class culpritWidget(undoableWidget, tearableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parentWidget, tabName):

        undoableWidget.__init__(self, parentWidget)
        tearableWidget.__init__(self, parentWidget, tabName)
```

I'm surprised the application worked at all.

Further investigation revealed undoableWidget needed not inherit from QWidget in the first place.

The application no longer hangs, and I am dizzy with relief.

Thank you for the advice. You have helped improve my debugging habits.